# How to make text fit in div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I'm styling a link to make it look like the photo. The problem is in the second div, text over div. In the scope of the question is an example of the photo of how it is and how it should be. (I left the text color in black to illustrate the problem)

[image]

How it should be

[image]

```js
  var div_color = document.getElementsByClassName('div-categoria');
  console.log
  div_color[0].style.backgroundColor = '#7d35ed';
  div_color[1].style.backgroundColor = '#e93f3f';
  div_color[2].style.backgroundColor = '#e4bf2a';
```

```css
  .categoria{
    margin: 2.5rem 0;

  }
  .div-categoria{
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform .2s;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative
  }
  .div-categoria:hover{
    transform: scale(1.10);
  }
  .categoria a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  .div-categoria p {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="categoria">
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Comida</p></div></a>
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas Alcoolicas</p></div></a>
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas</p></div></a>
</div>
```

Comment: does the width and height have to be 120px, or it could be bigger?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
  var div_color = document.getElementsByClassName('div-categoria');
  console.log
  div_color[0].style.backgroundColor = '#7d35ed';
  div_color[1].style.backgroundColor = '#e93f3f';
  div_color[2].style.backgroundColor = '#e4bf2a';
```

```css
  .categoria{
    margin: 2.5rem 0;

  }
  .div-categoria{
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform .2s;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative
 
  }
  .div-categoria:hover{
    transform: scale(1.10);
  }
  .categoria a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  .div-categoria p {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1

    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="categoria">
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Comida</p></div></a>
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas Alcoolicas</p></div></a>
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas</p></div></a>
</div>
```

now your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

just add css in your (.div-categoria p) block it will work

```
word-break: break-all;
text-align: center;
padding: 10px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS word-wrap property to .div-categoria p

```
.div-categoria p {
    margin: 0;
    color: black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
  }
```

or if you want to fit the text inside then try decreasing font-size ..

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace below class. It will fix your issue.

```
 .div-categoria p {
    margin: 0;
    padding:5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFF;
  }
```

```js
var div_color = document.getElementsByClassName('div-categoria');
  console.log
  div_color[0].style.backgroundColor = '#7d35ed';
  div_color[1].style.backgroundColor = '#e93f3f';
  div_color[2].style.backgroundColor = '#e4bf2a';
```

```css
.categoria{
    margin: 2.5rem 0;

  }
  .div-categoria{
    display: inline-flex;
    height: 120px;
    width: 120px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: transform .2s;
    margin-right: 20px;
    position: relative
  }
  .div-categoria:hover{
    transform: scale(1.10);
  }
  .categoria a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
  }
  .div-categoria p {
    margin: 0;
    padding:5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    color: #FFF;
  }
```

```html
<div class="categoria">
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Comida</p></div></a>
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas Alcoolicas</p></div></a>
  <a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas</p></div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To automatically fit to container, consider using a JavaScript helper library such as `textFit`.

[image]

```html
<html>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/textfit/2.1.0/textFit.min.js"></script>
<style>
.categoria{
margin: 2.5rem 0;
}
.div-categoria{
display: inline-flex;
height: 120px;
width: 120px;
border-radius: 10px;
transition: transform .2s;
margin-right: 20px;
position: relative
}
.div-categoria:hover{
transform: scale(1.10);
}
.categoria a{
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
}
.div-categoria p {
margin: 0;
color: black;
position: absolute;
text-transform: uppercase;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
text-transform: uppercase;
/*text-align: center;*/
}
</style>
<div class="categoria">
<a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Comida</p></div></a>
<a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas Alcoolicas</p></div></a>
<a href="#link"><div class="div-categoria"><p>Bebidas</p></div></a>
</div>

<script>
var div_color = document.getElementsByClassName('div-categoria');
div_color[0].style.backgroundColor = '#7d35ed';
div_color[1].style.backgroundColor = '#e93f3f';
div_color[2].style.backgroundColor = '#e4bf2a';

var p_list = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
window.textFit(p_list[0]);
window.textFit(p_list[1]);
window.textFit(p_list[2]);
</script>
</html>
```